# Error handling while using Application.Echo method

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was having a problem of screen flickering when running a module. Then decided to used the method `Application.Echo`
However, I have notice that, using `Application.Echo` method without Error handling causes my screen to go blank if indeed an error occurs within the module.
As a result, I have thought of two approaches and would like to know which approach would be more efficient and if indeed these are the right ways of dealing with this kind of problem.

Approach 1:

```
Sub loopThrough()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Me.Requery
Application.Echo False

'A for loop here........

 Application.Echo True

 exitErr:
 Application.Echo True
 Exit Sub

ErrorHandler: MsgBox Err.Description
GoTo exitErr

End Sub
```

Approach 2:

```
Sub loopThrough()
On Error Resume Next
Me.Requery
Application.Echo False

'A for loop here........

Application.Echo True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never go for approach 2, many things can go wrong here!

Take the following example code:

```
Sub loopThrough()
On Error Resume Next
Me.Requery
Application.Echo False
'Append new data to table
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM NewData", dbFailOnError
'Truncate the new data table, this data has been appended
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM NewData"
Application.Echo True
End Sub
```

Say `NewData` contained an entry that could not fit into `MyTable`. That operation fails, we continue on, truncate `NewData`, poof, data gone without a trace.

Did an error occur? Not a clue, because we didn't get notified of an error probably not? Oh, wait, there's missing data! How did that happen?

If you take your first approach here, you:

- Get an error message
- Don't delete your data if there's an error
- Have code that's a tiny bit lengthier

Do remind yourself not to call `Application.Echo True` twice, that's not necessary.

The usual structure in VBA for proper code is:

```
Public Sub SomeSub()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    'Usual code here

ExitHandler:
    'Perform operations needed when exiting, e.g. close open connections, set Application.Echo to true
    'Then exit:
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    'Report error here
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Note that I use the [`Resume` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/resume-statement). That's specifically intended to jump out of an error handler. As far as I know it has no direct benefits outside of being syntactically clear, but I'm not 100% sure of that.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. However, the `Resume` statement does not seems to disable the process triggered by the `Application.Echo False`  without using another `Application.Echo True` in the 'ExitHandler`. This makes the use of `Application.Echo True` twice inevitable and this makes me wonder.

Comment: The _twice_ here referred to in your normal script before the exit handler, and in the exit handler itself. If you need to display error messages in a messagebox then you can't get around it, but if you log errors/have a form to display errors/any other reasonable approach then you don't need to do this twice.

Comment: I see. Thank you